# Dropzone JS Global Events

Tags: javascript, dropzone.js

I might have this wrong but Dropzone JS seems to do things in a very odd way. http://www.dropzonejs.com/#events

This is the recommended method of adding an event

```
Dropzone.options.myAwesomeDropzone = {
  init: function() {
    this.on("addedfile", function(file) { alert("Added file."); });
  }
};
```

This assumes you know what `myAwesomeDropzone` is. But if you create them programatically then you may not know what `myAwesomeDropzone` is. It could be anything, e.g. if you have three different Dropzones on the  page based on some ID then the identifier won't be `myAwesomeDropzone` or even guessable.

It would be handy to be able to do

```
$(".dropzone").on("addedfile", function(file) {
    alert("hello");
});
```

But it does not work. I just want to be able to attach a global event to all my dropzones.

Answer (score 1):

If you have several dropzones in the same page, and you need for each one to have a different configuration, you have to initialize each one separately.
As I see you are using jQuery know that you can also initialize the dropzone elements using the Dropzone jQuery plugin already included in dropzone.

As example imagine that each dropzone accepts a different file type:

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$("#dropzone1").dropzone({
  url: 'urlForDropzone1.php', 
  acceptedFiles: 'application/pdf',
  init: function(){
    this.on("addedfile", function(file) { 
    alert("Added" + file.name + " on Dropzone 1."); 
    }),
    this.on("success", function(file) {
        alert(file.name " Uploaded from Dropzone 1")
    })
  }
});

$("#dropzone2").dropzone({
  url: 'urlForDropzone2.php', 
  acceptedFiles: 'image/*,.jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif',
  init: function(){
    this.on("addedfile", function(file) { 
    alert("Added" + file.name + " on Dropzone 2."); 
    }),
    this.on("success", function(file) {
        alert(file.name " Uploaded from Dropzone 2")
    })
  }
});
```

Notice that first you need to disable the autodiscover feature, then initialize each dropzone separately, the url are optional, don't need to include them if you already have them in the html.

Comment: But the generation is dynamic based on a database, so that means generating all the javascript dynamically too, because I do not know what IDs will or will not be present. Seems like a major downfall of dropzone.

Comment: @JakeN then, do the elements created have always the same ids or at least maintain an order inside the html?

Comment: They all have the same class

Comment: @JakeN but do they need to have a different configuration depending on the class? Can you inclulde an example of the html generated?

Comment: I have found the issue now. I thought autoDiscover was off, but it wasn't because dropzone was included twice

Answer (score 0):

You can append dropzone very similar as in your 2nd snippet. When you attach the configuration directly when initializing the dropzone.

```
  new Dropzone(".dropzone", {
                    url: 'someUrl',
                    addedfile: function () {
                        alert('Hallo');
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

The below works, my issue was that I had dropzone.js included twice which made `Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;` be ignored.

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;

$(".dropzone").on("addedfile", function(file) {
    alert("hello");
});
```